# filter duplicate URLs domain from List c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, filter

I have a list of 100,000 urls in list(Of string) which can contain urls in the form.

```
yahoo.com
http://yahoo.com
http://www.yahoo.com
```

i have tried using a combination of regex and the Uri class, but that didn't help, so i dumped the code. i also tried using this code, but it will only remove duplicatse of exact form, since its not domain specific.

```
list = new ArrayList<T>(new HashSet<T>(list))
```

How filter these duplicates and keep just one of these url if it contains the same name e.g yahoo.

thanks

[EDIT]

Please note that

all URL are of different domains, but can usually have duplicates like the example i gave above

also, am using .net 2.0, so i can't use linq

Comment: www.yahoo.com and yahoo.com are not the same, or do you want to just have domain.tld without subdomains?

Comment: Are all 100,000+ Urls some form of 'yahoo.com'? Are other Url domains going to be contained within the original list?

Comment: all URL are of different domain, but can usually have duplicates like the example i gave above

Comment: you didn't really answer my question. Do you only want to compare the domain part `domain.tld` or do you want to compare the `subdomain.domain.tld` as well and only treat the `www.domain.tld` as a special case?

Comment: @Damokles I want to compare only the domain part `domain.tld`, so this `www.domain.tld` and this `subdomain.domain.tld` is a duplicate. the `domain.tld` should be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var sites = new List<string> {"yahoo.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://www.yahoo.com"};

        var result = sites.Select(
            s =>
            s.StartsWith("http://www.")
                ? s
                : s.StartsWith("http://") 
                      ? "http://www." + s.Substring(7) 
                      : "http://www." + s).Distinct();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count());
    }
```

Comment: what is with e.g. `static.yahoo.com` ?

Comment: Yep, this would work if all 100,000 URLs were variations of yahoo.com. But I highly doubt it.

Comment: @Damokles. I assume static.yahoo.com is a different site from yahoo.com. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @LukeH I don't see why that url will fail. Am I missing something?

Comment: @IAbstract.The Linq query is agnostic of the actual site urls. Why do you think this will not work?

Comment: @boca yes that is what I mean, but as I said in the comment to the question www.yahoo.com and yahoo.com is also not the same.

Comment: @boca: My reading of the question is that the OP wants to treat all of `yahoo.com`, `images.yahoo.com`, `static.yahoo.com`, `www.yahoo.com`, `anything.else.yahoo.com` (and their variations prefixed with `http://`, `https://` etc) as duplicates.

Comment: @Damokles. I see your point, but I believe that is not what Smith asked. He wants to treat yahoo.com and www.yahoo.com as if they're the same.

Comment: @LukeH. Ok. Thats not what I gather from his question

Comment: @boca: my humble opinion, it is bad form to 'assume' everything is as clear cut as the Linq you provided (specifically surrounding the `StartsWith` & `Substring` functions). This process assumes that the Url is going to always use 'http', never 'https' (as others have pointed out)   :)

Comment: @IAbstract the urls are of different domains not all yahoo

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx) would be able to help in this case. I am not at a VS machine where I can test; however, pass the Uri constructor the string of the Url, and try the Host property for comparison:

```
List<string> distinctHosts = new List<string>();

foreach (string url in UrlList)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url)

    if (! disctinctHosts.Contains(uri.Host))
    {
        distinctHosts.Add(uri.Host);
    }
}
```

This feels a bit primitive, and could probably be more elegant - possibly without a `foreach`; but like I said, I'm not at a development machine where I could work with it.

I think this would be able to handle any variation of a valid Url. Building an ArrayList is not a good idea; in my opinion, Regex would require that you maintain some sort of custom 'MatchList' that could get unwieldy.

As @Damokles points out, you should have some form of validation. The Uri class *does* require a protocol: 'http://' or 'ftp://'. You do not want to assume 'badurl.com' is actually invalid; however:

```
if (!url.StartsWith("http://")) { /* add protocol */ } // then check Host domain as above
```

...should be sufficient simply to retrieve a distinct host or domain name. I recommend any option that does not require guessing the index position of any part of the Url as that is tightly bound to specific formats.

Comment: The uri creation will fail if you don't have a scheme/protocol in it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492.aspx

Comment: @Damokles: true enough; I would recommend validation anyway - if an invalid Url is in the list, it should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Uri class and Linq/extension methods. The trick is to normalize the Url before using it with the Uri class. Also note that the Uri class requires the scheme, so that will have to be added for ones where it's not present. You can use a different property of the Uri class to achieve different results. The example below returns all unique Urls and treats yahoo.com differently than www.yahoo.com.

```
string[] urls = new[] { 
  "yahoo.com",
  "http://yahoo.com",
  "http://www.yahoo.com" };
var unique = urls.
  Select(url => new System.Uri(
    url.StartsWith("http") ? url : "http://" + url).Host).
  Distinct();
```

(Edited to clean up formatting and to make the scheme addition part support both "http://" and "https://")

Comment: i am using .net 2.0, so i don't have linq

Answer (score 0):

Try a Regex then `.*?(\w+\.\w+)$` assuming you don't have anything after the tld.